# Embed Python in C++

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to call a Python function from the file `hello_world.py`:

```
def say_hello():
    print('Hello world from Python')
```

And I have a C++ code where I'm trying to call this function:

```
#include <python3.10/Python.h>
#include <exception>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();

    Py_SetProgramName((wchar_t*)argv[0]);

    PyObject *pModule, *pName, *pDict, *pFunc;

    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("hello_world");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "say_hello");
    PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work and it seems as if there are problems with pModule. When I watch in the debugger the value in it after `pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);` it still is `nullptr`.
**Can someone please help to figure out how to fix it?**

*Aditional info:*

I have such directories structure:

```
myProject
    CMakeLists.txt
    .idea
        ...
    src
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
        hello_world.py
```

File `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(myProject)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package (Python REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

File `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(.)

add_executable(myProject
        main.cpp)

find_package (Python REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

target_link_libraries(myProject PRIVATE Python::Python)
```

Comment: You should look into using [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).  Much easier to use than the CPython API.

Comment: Is `myProject/src` on your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)?

Comment: @0x5453, thanks, but I would like to investigate this approach. Maybe I try your recommendation a bit later

Comment: @0x5453, I'm not sure that `myProject/src` is in `PYTHONPATH`, how can I check it?

Comment: Open a terminal and use `echo $PYTHONPATH` on Linux or `echo %PYTHONPATH%` on Windows.  Python uses `PYTHONPATH` to determine what top-level directories it is allowed to `import` from, so that is likely the reason why your import is failing.

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` either modify your `PYTHONPATH` to include the directory with your python module, or (less recommended) go to this directory and exec your binary from there.

Comment: @0x5453, when I run `echo $PYTHONPATH` on Linux I get an empty line

Comment: But also if I call function `say_hello` in hello_world.py and run `python hello_world.py` it works

Comment: @0x5453, also `PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World from Embedded Python!!!')");` works fine. Do you know why the code above fails?

Comment: @0x5453, does the use of pybind11 will cause the same problem?

Comment: As you've described, the failing import is the main problem (as indicated by the fact that `pModule` is `nullptr`).  Neither `python hello_world.py` nor `PyRun_SimpleString` causes your module to be imported, which is why both of those are working.  To make the import work, `myProject/src` must be on your `PYTHONPATH`.  Pybind11 will have the same behavior, because that's just how the  import mechanism inside the Python interpreter works.

Comment: Alternatively, in your case it may make more sense to avoid imports entirely.  e.g. maybe you want to use something like [`PyRun_File`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_File) instead.